# Modify programmatically a RaiseAndSetIfChanged property (To move the Selected item)

Tags: c#, wpf

Given this property that changes the Selected File every time I click an item I my listBox:

```
public IMediaFile SelectedPlayListFile
{
     get { return this.selectedPlayListFile; }
     set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectedPlayListFile, value);
}
```

and called later with:

```
var file = this.SelectedPlayListFile;
```

How could i set the property without the RaiseAndSetIfChanged event? I need to change the SelectedPlayListFile programmatically and let the UI reflects that change too. (No more clicking)

So the SOLUTION was SO obvious...

```
this.SelectedPlayListFile = filesCollView.CurrentItem as IMediaFile;
```

Thank you for this newbie question.

Comment: Why do you want to omit `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` call?

Comment: If you simply set `SelectedPlayListFile` from code, it will notify the UI correctly... If you don't want the UI to be notified (?), use the field instead (`selectedPlayListFile`). There's nothing wrong with your code for what you're trying to do.

Comment: why not `this.SelectedPlayListFile = myNewMediaFile;` ?

Comment: This (obviously) did the trick: this.SelectedPlayListFile = filesCollView.CurrentItem as IMediaFile;